# How to filter a bitmap using Trilinear filtering or Anisotropic filtering in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap, filtering

I got a bitmap image, and application banners which need to be presentable.

I am using this function:

```
Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(src, width, height, bFilter);
```

It uses bFilter variable (true/false) to determine which filter to us, if it's true, it's bilinear filtering, otherwise Nearest-neighbor.

The problem is, that the results are the same, both are bad filters for me, see pic:

my pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5hIZ.png

I need to downsize the original pictures, and that comes out with both filters, as you can see, it is far from ideal, and I need some help.

After my search, I could not find any solution that uses some other filter then those 2 previously mentioned, so my question is:

```
How to proccess the bitmap with another filter, for example Trilinear or Anisotropic filtering, or any other for that matter?
```

Here is my code:

```
   private Bitmap GetBitmap(Drawable d, System.Drawing.Size? bounds)
   {
       int width = Math.Max(d.IntrinsicWidth, 1);
       int height = Math.Max(d.IntrinsicHeight, 1);
       if (bounds.HasValue)
       {
           width = Math.Min(width, bounds.Value.Width);
           height = Math.Min(height, bounds.Value.Height);
       }
       var bd = d as BitmapDrawable;
       if (bd != null)
       {
           Bitmap src = bd.Bitmap;
           if (width == src.Width && height == src.Height)
           {
               return src;
           }
           else
           {
               var bFilter = true;
               Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "bFilter:" + bFilter);   //<-----choose filter
               return Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(src, width, height, bFilter);
           }
       }
       Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
       d.SetBounds(0, 0, width, height);
       d.Draw(canvas);
       return bitmap;
   }


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5hIZ.png
```

Comment: The bilinear filtering will be used when scaling which has better image quality at the cost of worse performance. The nearest-neighbor scaling is used instead which will have worse image quality but is faster. If you do not want to use the bilinear filtering or nearest-neighbor, you could use the other methods to create the Bitmap without filter parameters. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap

Comment: @Wendy Zang - MSFT - but I want to give the end user more filter options, those listed here mention nothing about the filters mentioned in my question

Comment: If you want to use the filter options, you could use `createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)`  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean) and  `createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)`.  Only two methods include the filder options.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT you mean using the matrix? And if yes, do you know how? I have non expirience in that regard

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Also, does it make any sense to you, for me to convert the Dravable, or BitmapDrawable, or Bitmap to Drawable.Image, which I could use to meka a graphic object, which has other additional filters? See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: I check all the methods used to create the bitmap. Only two i provided in my previous comments could set the filter options. You could check the link i provided before.